# Dynamic variable parameter in static mysql query using groovy soap ui

Tags: groovy, soapui, dynamic-sql

I would like to generate the query that results for the BeneficiaryID 'ABC123' along with some other inputs if they were also given. Suppose if the currency value is given, I would like to include the Currency condition as well in the JOIN query, so as well the Category. I have the following code snippet in the **SOAP UI Groovy script**.

```
    query= " CORR.BeneficiaryID LIKE 'ABC123'"
    if (currencyValue!=""){
    query=query + " and  CORR.Currency LIKE '${currencyValue}'"
    }
    if (CategoryValue!=""){
    query=query + " and  CORR.Category LIKE '${CategoryValue}'"
    }
    log.info("Query" + query)

    Outputrows = sql.rows("select CORR.Preferred as preferred ,CORR.Category as  category,CORR.Currency as currency\
    from BENEFICIARY CORR \
    JOIN LOCATION LOC  on CORR.UID=LOC.UID and ${query}

    log.info("Output rows size" + Outputrows.size())
```

When currency and category are not given, I would like to have the following query run and get me the results.

```
select CORR.Preferred as preferred ,CORR.Category as  category,CORR.Currency as currency\
from BENEFICIARY CORR \
JOIN LOCATION LOC  on CORR.UID=LOC.UID and CORR.BeneficiaryID LIKE 'ABC123'
```

and when the currency and category are given(say USD & Commercial), then the following query.

```
select CORR.Preferred as preferred ,CORR.Category as  category,CORR.Currency as currency\
from BENEFICIARY CORR \
JOIN LOCATION LOC  on CORR.UID=LOC.UID and CORR.BeneficiaryID LIKE 'ABC123' and  CORR.Currency LIKE 'USD' and  CORR.Category LIKE 'Commercial'
```

All I could see on the result for `Outputrows.size()` is zero(0).

Can you please correct me where am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is changed script.

Since the issue to just build query, only putting that part remove `sql` execution part as that is not really the issue.

```
//Define the values or remove if you get those value from somewhere else
//Just put them here to demonstrate
//You may also try by empty value to make sure you are getting the right query
def currencyValue = 'USD'
def categoryValue = 'Commercial'
def query = 'select CORR.Preferred as preferred, CORR.Category as category,CORR.Currency as currency from BENEFICIARY CORR JOIN LOCATION LOC on CORR.UID = LOC.UID  and CORR.BeneficiaryID LIKE \'ABC123\''
currencyValue ? (query += " and CORR.Currency LIKE '${currencyValue}'") : query
categoryValue ? (query += " and CORR.Category LIKE '${categoryValue}'") : query
log.info "Final query is \n ${query}"
```

You can just pass `query` to further where you need to run the sql, say `sql.rows(query)`

You may quickly try <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5072371274743808)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Rao.. this is working as I intended it to be.